# Sorting a c++ vector of structs in a class

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector, struct

I have a class which basically looks like this(i removed unnecessary code):

```
class WilxList {
private:    
    struct Test{
        double number;
        int sign;
        int rank;
    };
    bool testSorter(const Test & x1, const Test & x2);
public: 
    WilxList(std::vector<double> &argNumbers, std::string argName, int numberOfTests);
};
```

I am trying to sort a vector of Test structs like that:

```
WilxList::WilxList(std::vector<double> &argNumbers, std::string argName, int numberOfTests)
{
    //Omitted code
    std::vector<Test> sortedTests;
    //Omitted code where Tests are created and added to the vector inside for loop
    std::sort(sortedTests.begin(), sortedTests.end(), testSorter); //ERROR
```

}

The error i get is:

```
error C3867: 'WilxList::testSorter': function call missing argument list; 
use '&WilxList::testSorter' to create a pointer to member
c:\users\stenver\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\wilxoniastakutest\wilxoniastakutest\wilxlist.cpp
```

Comment: Question was, how can i get rid of the error, but i got the answer already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`testSorter` is a **non static member function** of the class `WilxList` which is causing the difficulty. To use function pointers to non static member functions is relatively **more difficult**, and is impossible to use in cases which expect a free (or static member) function like the `sort` algorithm.

**One option** to fix this is to move `testSorter` into the struct itself and rename it to `operator<`. This will let you do stuff like `x1<x2` and you can call sort as just `std::sort(sortedTests.begin(), sortedTests.end());` This is assuming the function actually represents a `<` operation, if it isnt, it might get confusing and would be neater to just make it a **static member function**. The errors will go away in either case.

Comment: Thanks! I made it into static member function, just what i needed. For anyone in need of help or refrence: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the comparator function is a member function, which `std::sort` doesn't expect.

You can solve this in a number ow ways: The first is to make the comparator function `static`, another is to make it a free-standing function, a third way is to use a C++11 lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks! I made it into static member function!

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to:

```
class WilxList {
private:    
    static bool testSorter(const Test & x1, const Test & x2);
}

std::sort(sortedTests.begin(), sortedTests.end(), WilxList ::testSorter); //ERROR
```

Non-static `testSorter` takes an implicit `this` pointer which is incompatible being using as an predicate in `std::sort`, which takes two arguments.

Also you can declare `testSorter` as global function, either is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
 std::sort(sortedTests.begin(), sortedTests.end(), std::mem_fun(&WilxList ::testSorter));
```

or something similar. Check here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun/

Comment: Wont work since the objects being compared are `WilxList::Test` not `WilxList`